# Sketch the locus of points that satisfy $|z-1+i|<2.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Sketch the locus of points that satisfy $|z-1+i|<2.$

I know that $|z|=1$ is a circle around 1 but other then I don't know what to do.
Please help

What are the next step in doing this ?

Comment: hint: as you say, $|z-(0+0i)|=1$ is a circle but it is around $(0,0)$ with radius $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The distance between the numbers $z$ and $w$ in the complex plane is given by $|z - w|$.  You're looking for the locus of points which satisfy $|z - (1 - i)| < 2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write this as
$|z-(1-i)|<2
$,
you can see that
this is the set of points
that is within $2$
of
$1-i$.

In other words,
this is the interior
of the circle
with radius $2$
and center $1-i$.